# Package to create publication friendly table from model comparison

Tags: r

I have an ordinal mixed model from `clmm()` where I have done model comparison using `anova()` and now I'm looking for a package that could present the results in a publication friendly table for a word document.

I've tried `xtable`, `sjPlot` and have had a look at `stargazer` however none seem to be able to combine several anova objects to create a table. I don't want a table from the whole `clmm` output as there are several multilevel factors so the output is messy to say the least.

Instead I'd like a table showing the likelihood ratio, df and p-value from each model comparison, i.e. the outputs from my several anova outputs. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use RMarkdown and KableExtra with latex format.

Visit http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf.

It needs a latex compiler installed on your device.

You can transform the pdf to word using MS Office Word or something similar.